# CRM field mapping using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mapping, crm

I am a beginner in **Microsoft D365**, I want to map my price field from "book entity" to price field from "reader entity" as soon as book is selected from lookup on reader form, how can i achieve this using JS?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create any JS for this.
You can use OOTB functionality to do this.
First you need to create a relationship between this two entity then you can easily create a mapping between this two field inside the relationship.